# Python Windows environment error report: cl.exe failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, pip, pcl

I'm currently trying to install **pcl** lib
When running

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

I met a error reported as

```
cl.exe failed with exit status 2
```

I've installed VC++ 2022 build tools and Windows SDK to use standard libraries.

My python version is 3.7.6 and im trying to install pcl 1.8.1

**Am I missing a particular Microsoft program on my pc?**